# WordPress: load full size image in thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Because of using a magnifying glass script, I need to load the full image in the article (not featured image), even if the customer is choosing a thumbnail.

Example... this code should be generated:

```
<img src="..../uploads/image.png" width="300" height="500" />
```

and not

```
<img src="..../uploads/image-300x500.png" width="300" height="500" />
```

Anybody with a cool snippet for that? Thanks!

EDIT: I mean images that were used in the article, not the post/featured/thumbnail images-function.

Comment: But this is only for post thumnails/featured images, isn't it? I need something for images in the article.

Answer (score 3):

There are four valid sizes built in to the WordPress core.

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
```

The last is one you're looking for.

The following returns the URL. With **full size**.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail())
 $imageUrl =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full');?>
<img alt="Post Thumbnail" src="<?php echo esc_url($imageUrl[0]); ?>">
```

for **Blog Image** you can use -

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<img alt="Post Thumbnail" src="<?php echo esc_url($imageUrl[0]); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to **set image size in code** you can use following code in function.php file

```
<?php add_image_size('product-size-large',300, 500, true);?>
```

then use this size here

```
<?php $imageUrl =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'product-size-large'); ?>
```

> Also, for more options see the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/).

Comment: This solution is only for post thumbnails, isn't it? I need a solution for images that were put in the article...

Answer (score 1):

here is code for custom image upload in wordpress

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
    'your-custom-size' => __( 'Your Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}

// Assuming your Media Library image has a post id of 24...
echo wp_get_attachment_image( 24, 'your-custom-size' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the_post_thumbnail('full','true');
to get the original image size.
        OR 
You can also use

```
function get_the_post_thumbnail( $post = null, $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return '';
    }
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );
```

in your function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can get image thumbnail first then can inset in image tag. And in "get_post_thumbnail_id" you can insert any size that you define in your code. thumbnail is already define size in your function.php.

```
      <?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail');?>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url($thumbnail['0']); ?>" alt="Post Thumbnail"/>
```

Comment: This solution is only for post thumbnails, isn't it? I need a solution for images that were put in the article...