# WordPress: Load full size image in article-thumbnail format

Tags: php, wordpress

Because of using a magnifying glass script, I need to load the full sized images in articles, even if the customer is choosing a thumbnail-size like large, medium .....

I mean not the post-thumbnail, I mean images that were embed in the post itself. So any functions in relation to `the_post_thumnail` are not so helpful I think... :-)

Example... this code should be generated:

```
<img src="..../uploads/image.png" width="300" height="500" />
```

and not

```
<img src="..../uploads/image-300x500.png" width="300" height="500" />
```

Anybody with a cool idea for that? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress: load full size image in thumbnail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300618/wordpress-load-full-size-image-in-thumbnail)

Comment: Nope :-) the thread you mean is for post_thumbnails ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `image_send_to_editor` filter and serve a markup constructed by you, where you display the full image, like in the code below:

```
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'my_insert_image', 10, 9 );

function my_insert_image(  $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
    list( $img_src, $width, $height ) = image_downsize($id, $size);
    $hwstring = image_hwstring($width, $height);
    $class = 'align' . esc_attr($align) .' size-' . esc_attr($size) . ' wp-image-' . $id;
    $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'full' );
    $html = '<img src="' . esc_attr($img_src[0]) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($alt) . '" ' . $title . $hwstring . 'class="' . $class . '" />';

    return $html;
}
```